# E-bike stuttering up hills

Tags: electric-bike

Electric bike keeps stuttering going up hills only happened after a ride out in the rain could this have something to do with it

Comment: Does the problem persist after you thoroughly clean it and then dry it out?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what is stuttering?  Is the motor cutting out, or the display, or is the bike losing traction with the ground?   Is there a pedal-crank sensor that has to see motion before your motor assist kicks in?

Answer (score 1):

Water and electricity usually don't play well together.

In an e-bike, the most probable water-related malfunction sites are the brake sensors.

The next suspect would be the cadence sensor and the bronse medal goes to the controller (it is usually, but not always, watertight).

Each of these could be removed for inspection and drying.